# Duplicate Union entries when using NULL

Tags: mysql, null, union

I have a query that when I use a NULL in one of them it duplicates that line.

Basically when there is there is a person that made an entry on lance, it shows the max of all of those lances made about a certain leilao. (leilao =auction, lance = bid)

```
SELECT lr.lid,l.nome,datediff(date_add(l.dia,INTERVAL lr.nrdias DAY),current_date()) as "Nr dias até o fim",null
from leilao l JOIN leilaor lr  ON (l.dia= lr.dia AND l.nrleilaonodia = lr.nrleilaonodia AND l.nif= lr.nif) 
where date_add(l.dia,INTERVAL lr.nrdias DAY) >= current_date()
group by lid
UNION
SELECT lr.lid,l.nome,datediff(date_add(l.dia,INTERVAL lr.nrdias DAY),current_date()) as "Nr dias até o fim",MAX(la.valor)
from concorrente c JOIN lance la JOIN leilaor lr JOIN leilao l
ON (c.leilao = lr.lid AND la.pessoa = c.pessoa AND la.leilao = c.leilao AND l.nif=lr.nif AND l.dia= lr.dia AND l.nrleilaonodia = lr.nrleilaonodia) 
where date_add(l.dia,INTERVAL lr.nrdias DAY) >= current_date()
group by lid
```

By sugestion changed to this but it gives me an error "Every derived table must have its own alias.
Select *
from(

```
SELECT lr.lid,l.nome,datediff(date_add(l.dia,INTERVAL lr.nrdias DAY),current_date()) as "Nr dias até o fim",null as "Maxímo lance"
from leilao l NATURAL JOIN leilaor lr  
where date_add(l.dia,INTERVAL lr.nrdias DAY) >= current_date()
group by lr.lid
UNION 
(SELECT lr2.lid,l2.nome,datediff(date_add(l2.dia,INTERVAL lr2.nrdias DAY),current_date()) as "Nr dias até o fim",MAX(la.valor)
from concorrente c JOIN lance la JOIN leilaor lr2 JOIN leilao l2
ON (c.leilao = lr2.lid AND la.pessoa = c.pessoa AND la.leilao = c.leilao AND l2.nif=lr2.nif AND        l2.dia= lr2.dia AND l2.nrleilaonodia = lr2.nrleilaonodia)
where date_add(l2.dia,INTERVAL lr2.nrdias DAY) >= current_date() 
group by lr2.lid) 
)
group by Max(la.valor)
```

Comment: as NULL and actual max value are different, UNION will report both the rows, union will eliminate duplicates ( i.e all values are same )

Comment: so sugestion how to correct this?

Comment: But there's no aggregating function in the first query ?!!?

Comment: I should aggregate by what?

Comment: Have your union query as subquery and then do group by with max again